# Uvicorn can't find modules

Tags: python, fastapi, python-venv, modulenotfounderror, uvicorn

I have a folder that has my venv with dependencies and a python file.

When I run the python file with python main.py it works.

When I run the python file with `uvicorn main:app --reload` it throws a module not found error for all my dependencies. I want to turn the main.py into a fastapi app and installed fastapi and uvicorn to my venv and did `app = FASTAPI()`

Why is it working when running python but uvicorn is not finding my dependencies?

I uninstalled uvicorn and reinstalled it in my venv. I was expecting it to find my dependencies in my venv folder

Answer (score 3):

Probably you installed `uvicorn` outside of your virtual environment too, so when you run the command in terminal it tries to use that installation instead of the venv's version and doesn't find the dependencies.

Try calling `uvicorn` with the entire path, like this:

```bash
./venv/bin/uvicorn main:app --reload
```

Replace `./venv/` with the folder of your virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest solution for this to be to run uvicorn as a python module

```bash
python -m uvicorn main:app --reload
```

assuming the root of your problems is that your `uvicorn main:app --reload` is not respecting your venv

Answer (score 0):

make sure to activate your virtual environment: `source your_project_location/venv/bin/activate` on linux and on windows just write the path to activate file.
then with pip(while the virtual env activated) install any missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with pip. I was in my venv but when I ran pip it was for the /usr/local path not the venv path. To fix this I wrote out the path to the venv pip and installed it that way

This is not the best solution. When I run which uvicorn it still says `/usr/local/bin/uvicorn` and not my venv path

Answer (score 0):

When `which uvicorn` tells you the binary is at `/usr/local/bin/uvicorn`, it means two things:

- No virtual environment was active when installing Uvicorn.
- Uvicorn was installed as `root` or with `sudo`.

The following steps will ensure Uvicorn is instead running from your own virtual environment:

- Create a new virtual environment in your user's home directory:

  `python3 -m venv ~/uvicornvenv`
- Make your virtual environment active before you install any new module:

  `. ~/uvicornvenv/bin/activate`
- Update pip itself:

  `pip install -U pip`
- Install Uvicorn and FastAPI:

  `pip install uvicorn fastapi`

Make sure Uvicorn and FastAPI are installed correctly and are coming from your new virtual environment:

```
$ uvicorn --version
Running uvicorn 0.23.2 with CPython 3.10.12 on Linux

$ which uvicorn
/home/<youruser>/uvicornvenv/bin/uvicorn

$ pip show uvicorn | grep -E "Name:|Version:|Location:"
Name: uvicorn
Version: 0.23.2
Location: /home/<youruser>/uvicornvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages

$ pip show fastapi | grep -E "Name:|Version:|Location:"
Name: fastapi
Version: 0.103.1
Location: /home/<youruser>/uvicornvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

Whenever you want to use your virtual environment, and especially before you install other modules, do not forget to run `. ~/uvicornvenv/bin/activate` first!

I tested the above steps on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with Python 3.10.12.